# mapply for SparkR R

Tags: r, dataframe, sparkr, mapply

I have a Spark dataframe "a" with a header like  as follows

```
 C1 | C2 | C3 | C4  
 I1 | 12 | 31 | 4  
 I2 | 14 | 32 | 13  
 I3 | 13 | 33 | 15  
 I4 | 16 | 29 | 25  
 I5 | 18 | 30 | 73  
 I6 | 17 | 36 | 19
```

Column 2 (C2) is always smaller than C3

I want to compare C4 with C3 and C2 with the following logic:
if C4 is between C2 and C3 then return 1
else return 2

and add this as a new column to dataframe

I can do this with mapply when there is no Spark involved.
But how can I do this in SparkR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with just an ifelse statement

```
df_a <- data.frame(C1 = c('I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6'),
                C2 = c(12, 14, 13, 16, 18, 17),
                C3 = c(31, 32, 33, 29, 30, 36),
                C4 = c(4, 13, 15, 25, 73, 19))

a <- as.DataFrame(df_a)
a$C5 <- ifelse(a$C4 > a$C2 & a$C4 < a$C3, 1, 2)
head(a)
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1 I1 12 31  4  2
2 I2 14 32 13  2
3 I3 13 33 15  1
4 I4 16 29 25  1
5 I5 18 30 73  2
6 I6 17 36 19  1
```